# IE8 rendering images RGB

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

i'm having this issue.
Somehow ie8 is displaying the last image of the 3rd item of those important news somewhat broken. kinda weird why this is happening to this image only.
Those three images are JPG RGB 8bit. Not sure whats happening there..
Other explorers are working just fine

Problem in IE8:

[image]

Original image:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The image is RGB mode, not CMYK, so it should work, but it looks like IE 8 is buggy. PNG has always proven to be more reliable. I feel for you, friend: Internet Explorer is a darkness that has devoured the enthusiasm of web programmers for more than a decade now. I'd go with PNG 8-bit instead.

Comment: @dan i thought it could be a real problem (known one) from ie8 to render images.. since im not the one who changes these images, ill ask client to change them to png 8-bit image..